# Green's Function problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

I have the ODE:

$G(x,s)$ satisfies 
$$xG''-(2x+1)G'+(x+1)G= \delta (x-s)$$
 with $G(0,s)=G(1,s)=0$

I have that the general solution to the ODE 
$$xy''-(2x+1)y'+(x+1)y=0$$
 is $y(x)=c_1 e^x + c_2 e^x x^2$.

So my Green's function is: 
$f\left(x\right) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       G_+ = A(s)e^x+B(s)e^x x^2 & : 0 \le s < x \\
       G_- = C(s)e^x+D(s)e^x x^2 & : x < s \le 1
     \end{array}
   \right.\\
$

Using the initial boundary conditions, I get $C=0$ so $G_-=Dx^2e^x$ and $-A=B$ so $G_+=Ae^x-Ae^xx^2=Ae^x(1-x^2$) (I am assuming these are correct).

Using the jump conditions at $x=s$, where $[G]=G_+(s,s)-G_-(s,s)=0$ and $[\delta G/ \delta x]=1$

With this, I get $D=\frac {A(1-s^2)}{s^2}$ so now, $G_-=Ae^x(1-x^2)$

However, this means that $G_-=G_+$ and this doesn't make sense since $[\delta G/ \delta x]=1$ so I will get $0=1$.

I understand this may be a long question, but I am really struggling to see where I am going wrong. I have checked my values for $A,B,C,D$ over and I get them the same every time.

Any helo would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I think you choice of G is wrong. You should take G=A(s)e^x x^2 for s<x and G=B(s) e^x (1-x^2) for s>x. This way your boundary conditions are satisfied so you only have to apply the continuity and jump conditions.

Comment: How can I take these values? Do you mean for $G_+=Ae^x x^2$? How do i arrive at these?

Comment: You said yourself that $e^x x^2$ is a solution of the equation. You have to take G to be A(s) times a solution of the differential equation that satisfies the boundary condition at x=0 . And the same for x=1

Comment: Oh I see. I'll give this a try, thanks! Also, how did you know my choice of G was wrong so I can avoid this in future

Comment: Your G+ was $A e^{x} (1-x^2)$. This evaluated at x=0 is not zero. You should take a look at this article,they explain quiet well how to construct green functions http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~wparnell/MT34032/34032_GreenFunc.pdf

Comment: Oh so if I find my $G_+$ and the conditions I used was at $G=0$ at $x=0$ but $G$ isn't 0, then i must have chose the wrong $g$, right? thanks for your help

Comment: Also, I don't know how much you've done from Green's Functions, but an easy way to check your answer is correct is to see that your G is symmetric in s and x.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74034/discussion-between-patrick-and-juper).